# How can I pull all tags and their children from an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, foreach, xml-parsing

The XML data appears like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xmldata>
      <Orders>
        <OrderID>2119</OrderID>
        <AddressValidated>Y</AddressValidated>
        <Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>2.0000</Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>
        <AuthHash>d995fd9424fb99e80f58841a0ff2340f</AuthHash>
        <AVS />
        <BillingAddress1>122 27th West</BillingAddress1>
        <BillingAddress2>Floor 11</BillingAddress2>
        <BillingCity>New York</BillingCity>
        <BillingCompanyName />
        <BillingCountry>United States</BillingCountry>
        <BillingFaxNumber />
        <BillingFirstName>Dan</BillingFirstName>
        <BillingLastName>Test</BillingLastName>
        <BillingPhoneNumber>646456777</BillingPhoneNumber>
        <BillingPostalCode>10001</BillingPostalCode>
        <BillingState>NY</BillingState>
        <CardHoldersName />
        <CC_Last4 />
        <CreditCardAuthorizationDate>3/30/2012 11:52:00 AM</CreditCardAuthorizationDate>
        <CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>MANUAL</CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>
        <CreditCardTransactionID />
        <Customer_IPAddress>184.56.49.45</Customer_IPAddress>
        <CustomerID>19</CustomerID>
        <CVV2_Response />
        <GiftWrapNote />
        <IsAGift>N</IsAGift>
        <LastModBy>7</LastModBy>
        <LastModified>3/30/2012 1:39:00 PM</LastModified>
        <Locked>Y</Locked>
        <Order_Comments>Test sale - Don't process
    Ignore statuses on this order</Order_Comments>
        <Order_Entry_System>PHONE</Order_Entry_System>
        <OrderDate>3/30/2012 11:01:00 AM</OrderDate>
        <OrderNotes />
        <OrderStatus>Ready to Ship</OrderStatus>
        <PaymentAmount>8.1600</PaymentAmount>
        <PaymentMethodID>17</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum />
        <Processed_AutoEvents>Y</Processed_AutoEvents>
        <SalesRep_CustomerID>7</SalesRep_CustomerID>
        <SalesTax1>0.1700</SalesTax1>
        <SalesTax2>0.0000</SalesTax2>
        <SalesTax3>0.0000</SalesTax3>
        <SalesTaxRate>0</SalesTaxRate>
        <SalesTaxRate1>0.08375</SalesTaxRate1>
        <SalesTaxRate2>0</SalesTaxRate2>
        <SalesTaxRate3>0</SalesTaxRate3>
        <ShipAddress1>123 27th West</ShipAddress1>
        <ShipAddress2>Floor 1</ShipAddress2>
        <ShipCity>New York</ShipCity>
        <ShipCompanyName />
        <ShipCountry>United States</ShipCountry>
        <ShipFaxNumber />
        <ShipFirstName>Dan</ShipFirstName>
        <ShipLastName>Test</ShipLastName>
        <ShipPhoneNumber>646782342</ShipPhoneNumber>
        <Shipping_Locked>Y</Shipping_Locked>
        <ShippingMethodID>1</ShippingMethodID>
        <ShipPostalCode>10001</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipResidential>Y</ShipResidential>
        <ShipState>NY</ShipState>
        <Stock_Priority>3</Stock_Priority>
        <Tax1_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
        <Tax1_Title>Tax (8.375%)</Tax1_Title>
        <Tax2_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
        <Tax2_IncludePrevious>0</Tax2_IncludePrevious>
        <Tax2_Title />
        <Tax3_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
        <Tax3_IncludePrevious>0</Tax3_IncludePrevious>
        <Tax3_Title />
        <Total_Payment_Authorized>0.0000</Total_Payment_Authorized>
        <Total_Payment_Received>7.0700</Total_Payment_Received>
        <TotalShippingCost>5.9900</TotalShippingCost>
        <VendorID>0</VendorID>
        <OrderDetails>
          <OrderDetailID>3374</OrderDetailID>
          <AutoDropShip>Y</AutoDropShip>
          <FreeShippingItem>Y</FreeShippingItem>
          <GiftTrakNumber>0</GiftTrakNumber>
          <GiftWrap />
          <GiftWrapCost>0.0000</GiftWrapCost>
          <GiftWrapNote />
          <IsKitID />
          <KitID />
          <Locked>Y</Locked>
          <OnOrder_Qty>0</OnOrder_Qty>
          <OptionIDs />
          <Options />
          <OrderID>2119</OrderID>
          <ProductCode>test-product</ProductCode>
          <ProductID>39200</ProductID>
          <ProductName>Test Product 1</ProductName>
          <ProductNote />
          <ProductPrice>1.0000</ProductPrice>
          <ProductWeight>1</ProductWeight>
          <QtyOnBackOrder>0</QtyOnBackOrder>
          <QtyOnHold>1</QtyOnHold>
          <QtyShipped>0</QtyShipped>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <TaxableProduct>Y</TaxableProduct>
          <TotalPrice>1.0000</TotalPrice>
          <Vendor_Price>0.0000</Vendor_Price>
          <Warehouses />
        </OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetails>
          <OrderDetailID>3386</OrderDetailID>
          <AutoDropShip />
          <FreeShippingItem>Y</FreeShippingItem>
          <GiftTrakNumber>0</GiftTrakNumber>
          <GiftWrap />
          <GiftWrapCost>0.0000</GiftWrapCost>
          <GiftWrapNote />
          <Locked>Y</Locked>
          <OnOrder_Qty>0</OnOrder_Qty>
          <Options />
          <OrderID>2119</OrderID>
          <ProductCode>test-product</ProductCode>
          <ProductID>39200</ProductID>
          <ProductName>Test Product 2</ProductName>
          <ProductNote />
          <ProductPrice>1.0000</ProductPrice>
          <ProductWeight>1</ProductWeight>
          <QtyOnBackOrder>0</QtyOnBackOrder>
          <QtyOnHold>1</QtyOnHold>
          <QtyShipped>0</QtyShipped>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <TaxableProduct>Y</TaxableProduct>
          <TotalPrice>1.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
      </Orders>
      <Orders>
        <OrderID>2141</OrderID>
        <AddressValidated>Y</AddressValidated>
        <Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>1.0000</Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>
        <AuthHash>14cca8be8db44ca9943f0a6cbf592c83</AuthHash>
        <AVS />
        <BillingAddress1>122 27th West2</BillingAddress1>
        <BillingAddress2 />
        <BillingCity>New York2</BillingCity>
        <BillingCompanyName />
        <BillingCountry>United States</BillingCountry>
        <BillingFaxNumber />
        <BillingFirstName>Dan2</BillingFirstName>
        <BillingLastName>Test2</BillingLastName>
        <BillingPhoneNumber>646346322</BillingPhoneNumber>
        <BillingPostalCode>10002</BillingPostalCode>
        <BillingState>NY</BillingState>
        <CardHoldersName />
        <CC_Last4 />
        <CreditCardAuthorizationDate>3/30/2012 3:33:00 PM</CreditCardAuthorizationDate>
        <CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>MANUAL</CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>
        <CreditCardTransactionID />
        <Customer_IPAddress>56.75.23.34</Customer_IPAddress>
        <CustomerID>19</CustomerID>
        <CVV2_Response />
        <GiftWrapNote />
        <IsAGift>N</IsAGift>
        <LastModBy>7</LastModBy>
        <LastModified>3/30/2012 3:33:00 PM</LastModified>
        <Locked>Y</Locked>
        <Order_Comments>Test sale #2, don't process, ignore status.</Order_Comments>
        <Order_Entry_System>PHONE</Order_Entry_System>
        <OrderDate>3/30/2012 3:32:00 PM</OrderDate>
        <OrderNotes />
        <OrderStatus>Ready to Ship</OrderStatus>
        <PaymentAmount>7.0700</PaymentAmount>
        <PaymentMethodID>17</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum />
        <Processed_AutoEvents>Y</Processed_AutoEvents>
        <SalesRep_CustomerID>7</SalesRep_CustomerID>
        <SalesTax1>0.0800</SalesTax1>
        <SalesTax2>0.0000</SalesTax2>
        <SalesTax3>0.0000</SalesTax3>
        <SalesTaxRate>0</SalesTaxRate>
        <SalesTaxRate1>0.08375</SalesTaxRate1>
        <SalesTaxRate2>0</SalesTaxRate2>
        <SalesTaxRate3>0</SalesTaxRate3>
        <ShipAddress1>123 27th West2</ShipAddress1>
        <ShipAddress2 />
        <ShipCity>New York2</ShipCity>
        <ShipCompanyName />
        <ShipCountry>United States</ShipCountry>
        <ShipFaxNumber />
        <ShipFirstName>Dan2</ShipFirstName>
        <ShipLastName>Test2</ShipLastName>
        <ShipPhoneNumber>6461234789</ShipPhoneNumber>
        <Shipping_Locked>Y</Shipping_Locked>
        <ShippingMethodID>1</ShippingMethodID>
        <ShipPostalCode>10002</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipResidential>Y</ShipResidential>
        <ShipState>NY</ShipState>
        <Stock_Priority>3</Stock_Priority>
        <Tax1_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
        <Tax1_Title>Tax (8.375%)</Tax1_Title>
        <Tax2_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
        <Tax2_IncludePrevious>0</Tax2_IncludePrevious>
        <Tax2_Title />
        <Tax3_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
        <Tax3_IncludePrevious>0</Tax3_IncludePrevious>
        <Tax3_Title />
        <Total_Payment_Authorized>0.0000</Total_Payment_Authorized>
        <Total_Payment_Received>7.0700</Total_Payment_Received>
        <TotalShippingCost>5.9900</TotalShippingCost>
        <VendorID>0</VendorID>
<OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>3404</OrderDetailID>
      <AutoDropShip>Y</AutoDropShip>
      <FreeShippingItem>Y</FreeShippingItem>
      <GiftTrakNumber>0</GiftTrakNumber>
      <GiftWrap />
      <GiftWrapCost>0.0000</GiftWrapCost>
      <GiftWrapNote />
      <IsKitID />
      <KitID />
      <Locked>Y</Locked>
      <OnOrder_Qty>0</OnOrder_Qty>
      <OptionIDs />
      <Options />
      <OrderID>2141</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>test-product</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>39200</ProductID>
      <ProductName>Test Product</ProductName>
      <ProductNote />
      <ProductPrice>1.0000</ProductPrice>
      <ProductWeight>1</ProductWeight>
      <QtyOnBackOrder>0</QtyOnBackOrder>
      <QtyOnHold>1</QtyOnHold>
      <QtyShipped>0</QtyShipped>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TaxableProduct>Y</TaxableProduct>
      <TotalPrice>1.0000</TotalPrice>
      <Vendor_Price>0.0000</Vendor_Price>
      <Warehouses />
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

I need only the children of all `<OrderDetails>`

In testing I have tried to simply echo all of the data and then set variables once I had that.

```
function processxmldetails() {
$filexml='vl_rts.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
foreach ($xml->Orders->OrderDetails->children() as $Orders) {
echo $Orders . '<br>';
}
//end foreach
}
}
```

Which only echos this:

```
3374
Y
Y
0

0.0000



Y
0


2119
test-product
39200
Test Product 1

1.0000
1
0
1
0
1
Y
1.0000
0.0000
```

I need each `<OrderDetails>` really in it's own variable so I can check which `<OrderDetailID>` it is and insert into another database accordingly.

How can I call on these `<OrderDetail>` tags one by one and then check what their `<OrderDetailID>` is to perform a task, then move on to the next `<OrderDetail>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<?php
function processxmldetails() {
    $filexml = 'vl_rts.xml';
    $data = array();

    if( file_exists( $filexml ) ) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file( $filexml );
        $i = 0;

        foreach( $xml->Orders as $key => $orders ) {
            $j = 0;
            $data[ $i ] = array();

            $data[ $i ][ 'OrderID' ] = ( int ) $orders->OrderID;
            $data[ $i ][ 'OrderDetails' ] = array();

            foreach( $orders->OrderDetails as $key1 => $value ) {
                foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
                    $data[ $i ][ 'OrderDetails' ][$j][ $k ] = ( string ) $v;
                }
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
$result = processxmldetails();

foreach( $result as $key => $value ) {
    foreach( $value[ 'OrderDetails' ] as $k => $v ) {
        foreach( $v as $k1 => $v1 ) {
            echo $k1 .' = ' . $v1 . '<br />';
        }
        echo '----<br /><br />----';
    }
}
?>
```

All data within the `OrderDetailID` tag is now in the array. You can use it as per your requirements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay amazing, thank you. Can you tell me how to read the array? Like how can I call on the first OrderDetails line 1, then line 2, etc... then the second OrderDetails line 1, line 2 etc... ? Thanks so much.

Comment: I think I almost got it. So like $data[0][OrderID] is the first OrderID number and $data[2][OrderID] is the second ID number. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to call on the rest. I know, newbie questions... sorry.

Comment: You're the best, thank you so much! I needed $data[0][OrderDetails][0][OrderDetailID] and increasing those down the line to insert them. That bit there, calling on the code you wrote above, just saved me a world of headaches. I can see the light! Wooo!

Answer (score 0):

Alright since I can assume nothing this is what i have come up with 

This is the XML file we have for an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

This is the code we will use to pull our info :)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
```

And this will be our output

```
note
to: Tove
from: Jani
heading: Reminder
body: Don't forget me this weekend!
```

--Old code--Which i know realize was wrong langauge my mistake--
using the get child, you can pull in the information you need from each element

```
xml.getChild(index)
xml.getChild(path)
```

http://processing.org/reference/XMLElement_getChild_.html

best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering. Can I bother you for a quick example? I've never used that before. So say for example I want the first OrderDetails only, and I want to check the number of the first OrderDetailID tag then do some fancy stuff and move on to the second OrderDetails and do the same. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm going to add another answer, so i can break out the code for you

Comment: Thing is, and please tell me if I'm asking too much but, I really need an example based on the XML sample above. Note one <Order> has two <OrderDetails> and the other <Order> has only one <OrderDetails> and I need a clean way to call on them and their <OrderDetailID> so I can carry on with the script. Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: I would recommend the other answer that was provided, they go to using your code before me :)